# Getting empty subscription info when I login Azure using powershell workflow

Tags: powershell, azure, authentication, subscription

Hi I am trying to login Azure with `powershell workflow` and I get this result after successful authentication.

When i run this command  `Login-AzureRMAccount` in a `powershell workflow` and login with the `popup` window I get the below empty subscription info.

```
Environment           : 
Account               : 
TenantId              : 
SubscriptionId        : 
SubscriptionName      : 
CurrentStorageAccount : 
PSComputerName        : localhost
```

How can i get this to return the subscription info using `powershell` `workflow`.could you someone help please.

Comment: A couple of things for additional clarification. 1. Are you sure this account has subscriptions attached to ti? Just to be sure, log in to the azure portal and confirm that you have a subscription (pay as you go or visual studio or some other). 2. Have you tried with another account?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i get this to return the subscription info using powershell
>   workflow.

By default, Powershell workflow will not return the information, we can add two lines to get this information:

```
workflow jason{
$subscriptionId="5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxe29axxxx"
$tenantid="1fcfxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx8bf8xxxx"
$clientid="1498xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx6a17xxxx"
$password="7db8xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-93e2-xxxx0cb546f9"
$userPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
$userCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $clientid, $userPassword
Add-AzureRmAccount -TenantId $tenantid -ServicePrincipal -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId -Credential $userCredential 
$a = get-azurermsubscription | select Name,Id,TenantId
"$a"
}
```

The result like this:
[image]

Comment: Yes I could see the info but  I meant I wanted to be in the Azure session. So far when you see the blank info like you got after : means I am not int he Azure session. When I do it in normal powershell and login that populates fine and it shows I am in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried this and this works!

```
Connect-AzAccount -TenantId EnterTenantIDHereWithoutQuotes -SubscriptionId EnterSubscriptionIdHereWithoutQuotes
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work using the context this way. Once I logged in the first time. A context file was saved. IF the context file is already there it will auto login and I just uploaded the context file to the box or boxes that need to do the vm building and it will auto login. The below code is what I did in powershell to do a check for the context file if not it will prompt for the login.

```
 $ContextLocation = <Path to context file>
 $ContextPath = "$ContextLocation\ProfileContext.ctx"
     if ( -Not (Test-Path $ContextPath.trim() ))
        {
         Add-AzureRmAccount 
         # Now save your context locally (Force will overwrite if there) 
         Save-AzureRmContext -Path $ContextPath -Force 
         # Once the above two steps are done, you can simply import  
         Import-AzureRmContext -Path $ContextPath 
         $SubsName = Get-AzureRmSubscription | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' 
        }
        else
        {
         Import-AzureRmContext -Path $ContextPath 
         Write-Output $SubsName
        }
```